# pymssql - err msg - Adaptive Server connection failed, while connecting to sql sever

Tags: python-3.x

I am using pymssql to connect to sql server 2012 (SP4). I am getting the error - Adaptive Server connection failed

1. I have used this code earlier and it used to work
2. I am able to connect to SQL server using the same user id and password from SQL Server management studio
3. pyodbc.connect is able to connect to same server with the same credential
4. I have uninstalled pymssql and reinstalled again

pymssql version - 2.1.4
python - 3.6

I tried to connect to the SQL server from REPL. Please find the details -

```
pymssql.connect(server=r'sql.domain.com\DEV',port=1433,user='user',password='password',database='SCDINSD',tds_version="7.3")
```

Below is the tds dump

```
dblib.c:720:dblogin(void)
dblib.c:775:dbsetlname(0386EC18, user, 2)
dblib.c:775:dbsetlname(0386EC18, password, 3)
dblib.c:775:dbsetlname(0386EC18, pymssql=2.1.4, 5)
dblib.c:945:dbsetlversion(0386EC18, 7)
dblib.c:775:dbsetlname(0386EC18, UTF-8, 10)
dblib.c:775:dbsetlname(0386EC18, SCDINSD, 14)
dblib.c:4231:dbsetlogintime(60)
dblib.c:1180:tdsdbopen(0386EC18, sql.domain.com\DEV, [microsoft])
dblib.c:1206:tdsdbopen: dbproc->dbopts = 027FE900
dblib.c:1217:tdsdbopen: tds_set_server(02C86B70, "sql.domain.com\DEV")
dblib.c:257:dblib_get_tds_ctx(void)
dblib.c:1234:tdsdbopen: About to call tds_read_config_info...
config.c:169:Getting connection information for [sql.domain.com\DEV].
config.c:173:Attempting to read conf files.
config.c:359:... $FREETDSCONF not set.  Trying $FREETDS/etc.
config.c:372:... $FREETDS not set.  Trying $HOME.
config.c:302:Found conf file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming/.freetds.conf' (.freetds.conf).
config.c:510:Looking for section global.
config.c:569:   Found section global.
config.c:572:Got a match.
config.c:595:   tds version = '7.3'
config.c:932:Setting tds version to 7.3 (0x703).
config.c:583:   Reached EOF
config.c:510:Looking for section sql.domain.com\DEV.
config.c:569:   Found section global.
config.c:583:   Reached EOF
config.c:308:[sql.domain.com\DEV] not found.
config.c:298:Could not open 'c:\freetds.conf' ((default)).
config.c:359:... $FREETDSCONF not set.  Trying $FREETDS/etc.
config.c:372:... $FREETDS not set.  Trying $HOME.
config.c:302:Found conf file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming/.freetds.conf' (.freetds.conf).
config.c:510:Looking for section global.
config.c:569:   Found section global.
config.c:572:Got a match.
config.c:595:   tds version = '7.3'
config.c:932:Setting tds version to 7.3 (0x703).
config.c:583:   Reached EOF
config.c:510:Looking for section sql.domain.com.
config.c:569:   Found section global.
config.c:583:   Reached EOF
config.c:308:[sql.domain.com] not found.
config.c:298:Could not open 'c:\freetds.conf' ((default)).
config.c:810:Setting 'dump_file' to 'stdout' from $TDSDUMP.
config.c:714:tds_config_login: client_charset is UTF-8.
config.c:721:tds_config_login: database_name is SCDINSD.
config.c:214:Final connection parameters:
config.c:215:            server_name = sql.domain.com\DEV
config.c:216:       server_host_name = sql.domain.com
config.c:219:                ip_addr = 10.12.68.170
config.c:224:          instance_name = DEV
config.c:225:                   port = 0
config.c:226:          major_version = 7
config.c:227:          minor_version = 3
config.c:228:             block_size = 0
config.c:229:               language = us_english
config.c:230:         server_charset = 
config.c:231:        connect_timeout = 0
config.c:232:       client_host_name = JNJW7PF0UBWHQ
config.c:233:         client_charset = UTF-8
config.c:234:              use_utf16 = 1
config.c:235:               app_name = pymssql=2.1.4
config.c:236:              user_name = user
config.c:239:                library = DB-Library
config.c:240:              bulk_copy = 1
config.c:241:      suppress_language = 0
config.c:242:          encrypt level = 0
config.c:243:          query_timeout = 0
config.c:246:               database = SCDINSD
config.c:247:              dump_file = stdout
config.c:248:            debug_flags = 0
config.c:249:              text_size = 0
config.c:250:     emul_little_endian = 0
config.c:251:      server_realm_name = 
config.c:252:             server_spn = 
config.c:253:                 cafile = 
config.c:254:                crlfile = 
config.c:255:     check_ssl_hostname = 1
config.c:256:            db_filename = 
config.c:257:        readonly_intent = 0
log.c:168:Starting log file for FreeTDS 1.1.dev.20180827
    on 2019-01-31 13:41:50 with debug flags 0x4fff.
config.c:810:Setting 'dump_file' to 'stdout' from $TDSDUMP.
dblib.c:1261:tdsdbopen: Calling tds_connect_and_login(028993C0, 02B8CF08)
iconv.c:325:tds_iconv_open(02C03AE0, UTF-8)
iconv.c:347:setting up conversions for client charset "UTF-8"
iconv.c:349:preparing iconv for "UTF-8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:388:tds_iconv_open: done
net.c:1241:tds7_get_instance_port(10.12.68.170, DEV)
net.c:1316:instance info
0000 05 58 00 53 65 72 76 65-72 4e 61 6d 65 3b 55 53 |.X.Serve rName;US|
0010 43 4c 41 53 51 4c 56 53-32 30 30 32 3b 49 6e 73 |CLASQLVS 2002;Ins|
0020 74 61 6e 63 65 4e 61 6d-65 3b 44 45 56 3b 49 73 |tanceNam e;DEV;Is|
0030 43 6c 75 73 74 65 72 65-64 3b 4e 6f 3b 56 65 72 |Clustere d;No;Ver|
0040 73 69 6f 6e 3b 31 31 2e-30 2e 37 30 30 31 2e 30 |sion;11. 0.7001.0|
0050 3b 74 63 70 3b 31 34 33-33 3b 3b                |;tcp;143 3;;|
net.c:1357:instance port is 1433
net.c:391:Connecting with protocol version 7.3
net.c:318:Connecting to 10.12.68.170 port 1433
net.c:340:tds_setup_socket: connect(2) returned "A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately.
"
net.c:528:tds_open_socket() succeeded
packet.c:801:Sending packet
0000 12 01 00 32 00 00 00 00-00 00 1a 00 06 01 00 20 |...2.... ....... |
0010 00 01 02 00 21 00 04 03-00 25 00 04 04 00 29 00 |....!... .%....).|
0020 01 ff 09 00 00 00 00 00-02 44 45 56 00 80 3c 00 |........ .DEV..<.|
0030 00 00                  -                        |..|
packet.c:435:Received packet
0000 04 01 00 2b 00 00 01 00-00 00 1a 00 06 01 00 20 |...+.... ....... |
0010 00 01 02 00 21 00 01 03-00 22 00 00 04 00 22 00 |....!... ."....".|
0020 01 ff 0b 00 1b 59 00 00-02 00 00                |.....Y.. ...|
login.c:1237:detected flag 2
login.c:960:quietly sending TDS 7+ login packet
token.c:305:tds_process_login_tokens()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 636, in pymssql.connect
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1957, in _mssql.connect
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 676, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__
  File "src\_mssql.pyx", line 1683, in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (18456, b'DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (sql.domain.com\\DEV)\n')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-20-b2ea12ac01d3>", line 1, in <module>
    pymssql.connect(server=r'sql.domain.com\DEV',port=1433,user='user',password='Helloworld@16',database='SCDINSD',tds_version="7.3")
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 642, in pymssql.connect
pymssql.OperationalError: (18456, b'DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (sql.domain.com\\DEV)\n')
packet.c:435:Received packet
0000 04 01 00 88 00 5c 01 00-aa 70 00 18 48 00 00 01 |.....\.. .p..H...|
0010 0e 1f 00 4c 00 6f 00 67-00 69 00 6e 00 20 00 66 |...L.o.g .i.n. .f|
0020 00 61 00 69 00 6c 00 65-00 64 00 20 00 66 00 6f |.a.i.l.e .d. .f.o|
0030 00 72 00 20 00 75 00 73-00 65 00 72 00 20 00 27 |.r. .u.s .e.r. .'|
0040 00 74 00 39 00 73 00 61-00 75 00 32 00 27 00 2e |.t.9.s.a .u.2.'..|
0050 00 12 55 00 53 00 43 00-4c 00 41 00 53 00 51 00 |..U.S.C. L.A.S.Q.|
0060 4c 00 56 00 53 00 32 00-30 00 30 00 32 00 5c 00 |L.V.S.2. 0.0.2.\.|
0070 44 00 45 00 56 00 00 01-00 00 00 fd 02 00 00 00 |D.E.V... ........|
0080 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-                        |........|
token.c:313:looking for login token, got  aa(ERROR)
token.c:132:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is aa(ERROR)
mem.c:656:tds_free_all_results()
token.c:2389:tds_process_info() reading message 18456 from server
token.c:2461:tds_process_info() calling client msg handler
dbutil.c:75:_dblib_handle_info_message(02AC06F8, 028993C0, 0047EB4C)
dbutil.c:76:msgno 18456: "Login failed for user 'user'."
token.c:2478:tds_process_info() returning TDS_SUCCESS
token.c:313:looking for login token, got  fd(DONE)
token.c:132:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is fd(DONE)
token.c:2087:tds_process_end: more_results = 0
        was_cancelled = 0
        error = 1
        done_count_valid = 0
token.c:2106:                rows_affected = 0
token.c:2109:tds_process_end() state set to TDS_IDLE
token.c:422:tds_process_login_tokens() returning TDS_FAIL
login.c:537:login packet accepted
query.c:3773:tds_disconnect() 
util.c:165:Changed query state from IDLE to DEAD
util.c:319:tdserror(02AC06F8, 028993C0, 20002, 0)
dblib.c:8115:dbperror(036F6018, 20002, 0)
dblib.c:8183:dbperror: Calling dblib_err_handler with msgno = 20002; msg->msgtext = "Adaptive Server connection failed (sql.domain.com\DEV)"
dblib.c:8205:dbperror: dblib_err_handler for msgno = 20002; msg->msgtext = "Adaptive Server connection failed (sql.domain.com\DEV)" -- returns 2 (INT_CANCEL)
util.c:349:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:372:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
dblib.c:1265:tdsdbopen: tds_connect_and_login failed for "sql.domain.com\DEV"!
dblib.c:1478:dbclose(036F6018)
dblib.c:242:dblib_del_connection(0F4F1ED8, 028993C0)
mem.c:656:tds_free_all_results()
dblib.c:289:dblib_release_tds_ctx(1)
dblib.c:6051:dbfreebuf(036F6018)
dblib.c:750:dbloginfree(0386EC18)
```